# Detect if compiler is truly GCC (__GNUC__ is defined by other compilers too)

Tags: c, gcc, deprecated

How can I detect if the compiler is truly GCC, and not something pretending to be GCC, using the C preprocessor?

#### Motivation

Normally, I would test for `__GNUC__`. However, several compilers that claim to be compatible with GCC will define this, even though they are not fully compatible. Examples are Clang, Intel compiler, PGI.

At this time, I am looking to mark some enum values as deprecated, and I used an approach similar to the following:

```
#if __GNUC__ >= 6 || defined(__clang__)
#define DEPRECATED_ENUMVAL __attribute__ ((deprecated))
#else
#define DEPRECATED_ENUMVAL
#endif


enum Foo {
    A = 0,
    B DEPRECATED_ENUMVAL = A
};
```

This works in GCC version 6 and later, hence the check for `__GNUC__ >= 6`. However, it does not work with recent Intel and PGI compilers, even though both of those define `__GNUC__` to be `7`.

It seems that it would be safest to try to detect if I am dealing with specific versions versions of actual GCC or Clang, and restrict the deprecation attribute to them only. How can I detect an actual GCC?

Comment: You'll probably have to go poking around the macros defined automatically by the Intel and PGI compilers to see how they identify themselves, and work from that.  You can get the predefined macros printed in GCC using `gcc -E -dM empty-file.c` (see GCC [Preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)).  I got 337 lines of output from GCC 11.2.0 on a Mac.

Comment: Maybe I should look into detecting the availability of this feature with CMake. I would prefer to avoid detecting Intel or PGI specifically, as I'm sure there are other GCC-mimicking compilers out there that I don't even know about and that also don't support enum value deprecation.